# sending input parameters to another function

Tags: c++

I need to send the list of the input arguments to readInput function. But the compiler gives error when I call readInput function. Could you please tell me where my mistake is?

```
bool readInput(netcorr net,int argc, char * argv[]);

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    netcorr net;
    bool error=readInput(net, argc, argv);
}

bool readInput(netcorr &net,int argc, char * argv[])
{
}
```

thanks for your help.
Pegah

Edit: The compiler says

> Fehler: Argument 3 von »`bool readInput(netcorr, int, char**)`« wird initialisiert
>
> Fehler: ungültige Umwandlung von »char* const*« in »char**«

Translation by aschepler:

> Error: Argument 3 of '`bool readInput(netcorr, int, char**)`' is initialized
>
> Error: invalid conversion from 'char* const*' to 'char**'

Comment: You missed the `const` before `argv` in `readInput` definition

Comment: When I was in uni, I would debug C++ by throwing in `*`, `&`, and `const` in different places until it worked. Now I'm a Java guy. :-O

Comment: The compiler already told you what the mistake is... you should at least paste the compile error text in your question.

Comment: @glowcoder this is easy to understand
1. In variable declaration * means pointer and & means reference
2. In variable using * means dereferencing & menas address of variable

Comment: FYI: it is also usually a good idea to add the compiler error messages.

Comment: The compiler error is in German and googl translate can't translate properly. it was the reason that I did not send it: Fehler:   Argument 3 von »bool readInput(netcorr, int, char**)« wird initialisiert

Comment: @digEmAll adding const does not work.

Comment: Added error message to the post.  But I don't think you repeated the entire German error message.

Comment: @aschepler I added the second message too. thanks for your help.

Comment: @tenfour  I added my error. could you have a second look please?

Comment: @FYI I added my error. could you have a second look please?

Answer (score 3):

Because you try to redirect `char * const[]` to `char*[]`. Change your main function to get `cahr *[]` or change readInput function to get `char *const[]`.

Comment: @ Mihran Hovsepyan that does not work. the error is:
undefined reference to `readInput(netcorr, int, char**)

Comment: @Martin in question there was no point to give answer that accepts all ISO standarts, I just give solution of his problem. Also I don't think in nowdays you can find any compiler that doesn't accept char *const[] as type of argv of main function.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a function taking `netcorr` as it's first argument, and then defined one taking `netcorr&` as it's first argument. In addition, you tried to pass a `char* const[]` as a `char*[]`.